# List and foreach

Tags: c#, wpf, listview, foreach

I seem to be having a very weird problem and I really have no idea what's going on. This is the source code I'm trying to debug

```
StorageFile file = await roamingFolder.GetFileAsync(filename);
string text = await FileIO.ReadTextAsync(file);

string[] shows = text.Split(new[] { ":?;" }, StringSplitOptions.None);
List<show> showslist = new List<show>();

foreach (string splitshow in shows)
{
    string[] show1 = splitshow.Split(new[] { ",?;" }, StringSplitOptions.None);
    episode = show1[0];
    name = show1[1];

    showslist.Add(new show { name = name, episode = episode });
}

Output.ItemsSource = showslist;
```

The weird thing is that the list is shown only if I put `Output.ItemsSource = showslist;` inside of the foreach loop but not when it's outside and I really don't understand why it's not. I mean elements of the list have already been added to it haven't they??

Have tried many different methods and most of them even if they did show the list data had many different problems that are too messy to fix.

Anyway appreciate any hint or help, thank you.

Comment: Is showslist empty after the foreach when you debug it?

Comment: @Roeland yeah the showlist is empty after the foreach when I debug it

Comment: bah.  there must be more code executing that you aren't showing us.

Comment: @RobertLevy yea there is more code, don't really think it's important but I guess I'll add it...  edit:added

Comment: Not that it looks like it has anything to do with your issue - but why are you doing async operations with an immediate await? You're just turning them right back into synchronous operations again.

Comment: Where are episode and name declared?

Comment: I know this is really obvious, but `text` and `shows` do have the stuff that you expect in them before the loop.

Comment: @ColinMackay - this is better than old fashioned sync operations because 1) the code is readable and 2) this code can be called from the UI thread and not actually block the UI thread during I/O.  it's a great use of async

Comment: Sometimes it helps to set the `ItemsSource` to `null`: `Output.ItemsSource = null; Output.ItemsSource = showslist;`. (At least it does woth `DataSource`.)

Comment: episode and name are declared outside of the function and `text`  and `shows` do have stuff in them, like I said the output is shown if I put `Output.ItemsSource = showslist;` in the `foreach` so they're not empty...

Comment: Does this has the same problem? showslist.Add(new show { name = show1[0], episode = show1[1] });

Comment: Put a try/catch around it or check logging. Maybe, possibly, one of the later/last entries is throwing an exception and the exception is being swallowed higher up in your code (or not being reported to your logger/UI). Thus it never actually assigns the ItemSource or completes the foreach loop? (for example, maybe your song list data in your second split somewhere only produces _one_ element, so when you try to access its `name = show[1]` it throws an `IndexOutOfRangeException`)

Comment: @MusbahSinno Can you post the _exact_ data being used (i.e., the value of `text` in your code)?

Comment: @ChrisSinclair oh you were right, I got an `IndexOutOfRangeException`.The value of text is pretty long and weird but it's basically along those lines **hlj,?;lljhjh:?;hhmm,?;drr:?;oo,?;hello:?;ff,?;ff:?;**  the thing is my program basically stores information then reads it with the function above.

Comment: @MusbahSinno Thanks for the sample data, I can see the problem (see my answer)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I'll bet that your data isn't exactly correct. I think one of the later/last entries is throwing an exception and it's being swallowed higher up in your code (or not being reported to your logger/UI). It never completes the `foreach` loop and exits the method before you can assign your data source.

I would guess that your second split, one of the entries does not actually contain your delimiter `,?;` so the `show1` array is only of length 1 and does not contain a "name" entry. When you try to access `show1[1]`, it throws an `IndexOutOfRangeException`.

As an aside, might I suggest that you investigate using simpler delimiters, or better yet, utilize some form of XML (or JSON, or other) serialization for reading your data.

EDIT: I see from your posted code sample in your comments, that the issue is the last entry. Given `hlj,?;lljhjh:?;hhmm,?;drr:?;oo,?;hello:?;ff,?;ff:?;`, your first `String.Split` operation on `:?;` will yield an empty string as the last entry. Thus when you try to perform your second split against `,?;` it splits against empty and returns an array with a single entry of `String.Empty`. When you hit `show1[1]` the exception is thrown.

If you change your first split to use `StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries` it should eliminate the empty entry:

```
string[] shows = text.Split(new[] { ":?;" }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

If you like, you can add a check like `if (show1.Length == 2)` then you can avoid bad data (but perhaps you would prefer to report that so you can fix it). If your program is writing this bad data itself, perhaps you should make a couple quick unit tests to ensure that you're always writing/reading valid data.

Comment: Just looked at the data thoroughly you're right the delimeter at the end is the problem,It's pretty much as you said it, thank you for your help and thank you for the suggestions I'll research more about them and maybe use one of them.